# grid search random forests "RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet"

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, grid-search

Im trying to do grid search on random forests classifier, I'm trying to test different PCA componenet and n_estimators

```
  model_rf = RandomForestClassifier()
  pca_rf = Pipeline([('pca', PCA()), ('rf', RandomForestClassifier())])

  param_grid_rf = [{
                'pca__n_components': [20],
                'rf__n_estimators': [5]
                }]

  grid_cv_rf = GridSearchCV(estimator=pca_rf, cv=5,param_grid=param_grid_rf)
  grid_cv_rf.fit(x_train, y_train1)
  test_pca_evaluate = pca.transform(x_test)
  y_pred = model_rf.predict(test_pca_evaluate)#error here
```

In the last line I get an error "This RandomForestClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this method."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a pretty straightforward error - the `RandomForestClassifier` whose method you're calling hasn't been fit yet, meaning you haven't called `model_rf.fit`. That object isn't fitted by your `grid_cv_rf` object.

I think what you want is `grid_cv_rf.predict(x_test)`, because that `grid_cv_rf` object does both your PCA as well as RF fitting.